# Prime-counting function and divisor function

Tags: limits, number-theory, prime-numbers

$\pi(x)$ is the prime-counting function (i.e the number of primes less than or equal to an integer $x$), $\sigma(x)$ denotes the divisor function which sums the divisors of $x$.
Is the following statement correct?

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \sigma(\pi(2x+1)+1)=4k$$

Where $k$ is an integer (i.e $\sigma(\pi(2x+1)+1)$ is divisible by $4$ when $x$ tends to $+\infty$).

Thanks.

Comment: I think that the limit of $\sigma(x)$ when $x$ tends to infinity is indeterminate.

Comment: So why would you think it might be correct?

Comment: Hard to imagine that this expression is divisible by $4$ for all sufficiently large integers $x$ (I assume that $x$ is an integer, otherwise the limit clearly does not exist). Even if this were the case, there would still not be a limit , this is only the case if the expression would eventually become costant which almost surely is not the case.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: I tested the hypothesis numerically but I failed to compute very large numbers. Intuitively I think that the limit of $\pi(x)$ is $+\infty$

Comment: You don't need large numbers. You just need $x$ such that $\pi(2x+1)$ is of the form $p-1$, where $p$ is a prime congruent to one modulo four.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I found this problem by intuition but it might be hard to prove it (or impossible?)

Comment: $\pi(2x+1)$ increases by either $0$ or $1$ every time $x$ increases by $1$, as either $2x+1$ is prime or it isn't, and except for $2$, $2x$ is never prime. This means the internal expression takes on every integer value except $1$ as $x$ increases. No matter how large, you will have values of $\pi(2x+1)+1$ equal to a $4k+1$ prime every so often, and $\sigma(4k+1 \in \mathbb{P}) = 4k+2$, which is not divisible by four.

Comment: @Eric Snyder: thank your for your answer. But if $x$ denotes an integer such that $\pi(2x+1)=p+1$ where $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ we have $\pi(2x+1) \equiv 2 \pmod 4$, so $\pi(2x+1)+1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $\sigma(\pi(2x+1)+1) \equiv 0 \pmod 4$. Where is my error? If this is correct, it remains to prove that if $x$ denotes an integer such that $\pi(2x+1)=p+1$ where $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ we have $\pi(2x+1) \equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

Comment: You have misread what @Eric and I have written. We want $\pi(2x+1)=p-1$ where $p$ is prime and $p=4m+1$.

Comment: @CrawCraw What you've said is true, for that subset of integers. But $\pi(2x+1)+1$ will take on every positive integer value above $2$. It will hit every $4k+1$ prime, every $4k+3$ prime, and everything in between. Effectively your claim is equivalent to $\lim_{x \to \infty}\sigma(x) = 4k$. But that limit is undefined; it jumps everywhere.

Comment: In fact, I made a mistake. I better understand. Thanks.